# PostgreSQL calculate difference between multi rows total second

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
rid m_id      prosessdate          m30 door cutting
1   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:12 1   0   0
2   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:13 1   0   0
3   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:14 1   0   0
4   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:15 1   0   0
5   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:16 1   0   0
6   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:17 1   0   0
7   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:18 1   0   0
8   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:19 1   0   0
9   536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:20 1   0   0
10  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:21 1   1   0
11  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:22 1   1   0
12  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:23 1   1   0
13  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:24 1   1   0
14  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:25 1   1   0
15  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:26 1   1   0
16  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:27 1   1   0
17  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:28 1   1   0
18  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:29 0   0   0
19  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:30 0   0   0
20  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:31 0   0   0
21  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:32 0   0   0
22  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:33 0   0   1
23  536477698   05-07-2023 11:05:34 0   0   1
```

i am using PosgreSQL
I tried to calculate difference between rows in a field using a query:

I Need  when  m30 = 1 to door =1   calculate different second

05-07-2023 11:05:21   - 05-07-2023 11:05:12

cutting = 1  to door = 1   calculate different second

05-07-2023 11:05:33  -  05-07-2023 11:05:21

how can i do this.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and share the expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the rows you want.

For example:

```
select m.m_id,
  d.prosessdate - m.prosessdate as diff1,
  c.prosessdate - d.prosessdate as diff2
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by m_id order by prosessdate) as rn
  from t where m30 = 1
) m
join (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by m_id order by prosessdate) as rn
  from t where door = 1
) d on d.m_id = m.m_id and d.rn = 1
join (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by m_id order by prosessdate) as rn
  from t where cutting = 1
) c on c.m_id = m.m_id and c.rn = 1
where m.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
m_id       diff1     diff2
---------  --------  --------
536477698  00:00:09  00:00:12
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AVwLBg7B).

Comment: total row number more than 10k. Could you edit your answer in loop

Comment: For 10k rows this should be pretty much instantaneous. Nevertheless, an index on `(m_id, prosessdate)` could help a lot.